# How do I loop through chars in a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach

I have the following js and receiving error at the `foreach` loop:

```
function bitCount(n) {
var strBitCount = (n >>> 0).toString(2);
var answer = 0;
var c = '';

foreach(c in strBitCount)
{
    if(Number(c) == 1)
    {
        answer++;
    }
}
  return answer;
}
```

Comment: `forEach` is an array method:  `arr.forEach(function (el) {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `filter` on those characters in the string that match your test and return the length of that array.

```
function bitCount(n) {
  var strBitCount = (n >>> 0).toString(2);
  var equalsOne = function (char) { return +char === 1; }
  return [].filter.call(strBitCount, equalsOne).length;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/468tdn2m/)

Comment: Very nice sir!  and elegant.

Answer (score 16):

JavaScript has no `foreach` block as other languages.

What you can do is using `Array.prototype.forEach`:

```js
Array.from("hello").forEach(function(character) {
  console.log(character);
});
```

Well, and in ES2015 and above, you can use `for..of`

```js
for (let character of "hello") {
  console.log(character);
}
```

Comment: I accidentally hit the downvote I think....mad it an upvote...thanks for your answer.

Comment: @JeffOrris No problem. I've checked you found more useful other answer. BTW I still think that now you know that `foreach` doesn't syntactically exist in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an ordinary `for` loop and index into the string with `[]`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < strBitCount.length; ++i)
  if (Number(strBitCount[i]) === 1)
    answer++;
```

Note that you could also just add the digit to `answer`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < strBitCount.length; ++i)
  answer += Number(strBitCount[i]); // or +strBitCount[i]
```